# Insert entity to MongoDb async not working

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, asynchronous

could somebody tell me why this code not working ? It compiles, it runs but the Mongo database is still empty. It is working when doing it synchronously.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var client = new MongoClient();
        var db = client.GetDatabase("Mongo");
        var collection = db.GetCollection<User>("Users");

        User user = new User("Denis", "Chang", "China", 21);
        AddUserAsync(user, collection);
    }

    static async void AddUserAsync(User user, IMongoCollection<User> collection)
    {
        await collection.InsertOneAsync(user);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not waiting for `AddUserAsync` to complete. In order to do so, you have a couple of options:

1. Use `AddUserAsync(user, collection).GetAwaiter().GetResult()`, which will block until the asynchronous function completes.
2. If you're using C# 7.1, you can use an `async Main`, like so:

   ```
   static async Task Main()
   {
       ...
       await AddUserAsync(user, collection);
   }
   ```

In order for either of these approaches to work, you'll also need to update your `AddUserAsync` function to return a `Task`, simply by changing the signature:

```
static async Task AddUserAsync(User user, IMongoCollection<User> collection)
```

Comment: Stephen Cleary wrote an excellent [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) on this stuff, which you might find interesting.

Answer (score 0):

The method is asynchronous but you do not wait for the completion of the operation. Try this

```
static async Task AddUserAsync(User user, IMongoCollection<User> collection)
{
    await collection.InsertOneAsync(user);
}
```

and then

```
AddUserAsync(user, collection).Wait();
```

Comment: Settings are correct.It is working when doing it synchronously.